# slider with an expanded content depending on the height of the content on the next slide it all collapse when clicking "more"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a slider with content the expands with a read more toggle i have it set to expand the div according to the size of the content. the first one works great but as i advance to the next slide and click to read more to expand the whole div collapses and the height is set to 0px

```
if ($(currentslide).css('display') == 'block') {
    $('#super-slideshow-2').height($(".slider_area").height() + "px");
} else if ($(currentslide).css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#super-slideshow-2').height(318);
};
```

Comment: Looks like you are ding something very simple in very complicated way. Anyway you can use `$(currentslide).is(':visible')` or `:hidden`. Create a fiddle and surely you can get a better answer.

Comment: i could do it that way but it would still not fix my height collapsing upon the next slide

Answer (score 0):

it appears that in case of next slide

`$(".slider_area").height()` is equal to 0. You can confirm the value by using

```
console.log($(".slider_area").height());
```

for a complete solution some more part of the code will be required.

Comment: cant i use a return false after                                $('#super-slideshow-2').height($(".slider_area").height() + "px");